# Trying to prompt for 10 numbers for my array to do a mode

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, logic, java.util.scanner

The exercise I'm trying right now will require me to to

- Gather 10 values from the user to store into an array
- Display the mode of the 10 values
- (possible using a parallel array to count the occurrences of the values)
- use a method to use entered values as a parameter for and return the array with max values in order

This is the code I have so far:

The issue is that my mode worked for 10 DEFINED values but once I tried to mess with it and add the scanner for the values I lost myself

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int[] arraytwo = {10};
    test3(arraytwo);
    number = scan.nextInt;
    number = arraytwo[i];
}
public static void test3(int[] array)
{
    int modeTrack[] = new int[10];
    int max =0; int number =0;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    {
        modeTrack[array[i]] += 1;
    }

    int maxIndex = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < modeTrack.length; i++)
    {
        int newNum = modeTrack[i];
        if (newNum > modeTrack[maxIndex])
        {
            maxIndex = i;
        }

    }System.out.println(maxIndex);
}
```

Comment: `int[] arraytwo = {10};` What exactly are you trying to do here?

Comment: I'm trying to establish that I will only accept a maximum of 10 values into my array

Comment: Then you should write `int[] arraytwo = new int[10];` instead. What you wrote means that you have an array of one value, 10.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your test3() method isn't what's giving you trouble so I'll talk a bit about your main() method.

You have a few errors in your main() denoted by comments I have inserted:

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int[] arraytwo = {10};
    test3(arraytwo); 
    number = scan.nextInt; //number does not exist in this scope, also nextInt method should use () to call it.
    number = arraytwo[i]; //i does not exist in this scope
}
```

For the main method, I suggest you do something like the following:

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    Integer[] arrTwo = new Integer[10];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        arrTwo[i] = scan.nextInt();
    }
    sort(arrTwo);
    //System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arrTwo)); //this line will print your sorted array for you..
}
```

For the sort method you could do something like the following:

```
public static void sort(Integer[] arr){
    Arrays.sort(arr, Collections.reverseOrder());
}
```

Comment: is there a way to use the scanner instead? I tried that exactly with the scanner and got an error of readLine()

Comment: is it br.next();       ?

Comment: it worked out. Is there a way to display back the values in another array is descending order?

Comment: would I use a bubblesort somehow?

Comment: This post has some good thoughts on how to sort arrays of ints: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9791024/int-array-sort-lowest-to-highest.

Comment: @user3543981 please mark post as answered if you feel your question is answered

Comment: Will do. Can you help me with the sort? I utilized those resources and have come up with 

``Arrays.sort(arrTwo)
  System.out.println("Sorted :  ");
  for (int Arri : arrTwo)
  {
   System.out.println(Arri);
  }``

Comment: Sorry, I somehow missed the fact you needed to sort them in descending order. I've added it to my answer. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

This code will take ten values and sort them in descending order..Hope it will help you..save below code in Test.java and run it

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {

        Integer[] array = new Integer[10];
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        for (int i = 0; i <10; i++) {
            array[i] = scan.nextInt();
        }

        doSort(array);
    }

    static void doSort(Integer[] array)
    {
        Arrays.sort(array,Collections.reverseOrder());

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(array[i]);
        }
    }

}
```