# Method to sort an array from least to greatest Java

Tags: java, sorting

Hi I am trying to create a method that finds the mode of an array. To do this I first need to create a method that sorts the list from least to greatest but I am not sure what I am doing wrong in the first place

```
public class Mode {
    public int [] sort(int[] asd) {
        int[] sorted = new int[10];
        for (int i = 0; i < asd.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j < asd.length; j++) {
                if ( (asd[i] > asd[j]) && (i != j) ) {
                    int temp = asd[j];
                    asd[j] = asd[i];
                    asd[i] = asd[temp];
                }
                else
                    continue;
            }
        }
        return sorted;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Mode list1 = new Mode();
        int[] array = {3,2,5,4,1,1,1,1,10,9};
        int[] potato = list1.sort(array);
        for (int i = 0; i < potato.length; i++)
            System.out.print(potato[i]);
    }
}
```

When I run this, I get 0000000000 as an output. I think there is something wrong in the method since I am returning an array that has been initialized but nothing has been put in there. How do I (in my nested for loop) add each number in the sorted array?

Comment: `asd[i] = asd[temp];` should be `asd[i] = temp`;

Comment: You are sorting array `asd` in-place, but then returning `sorted` which is initialized as zeros. Try copying array `asd` into `sorted`, and then sorting array `sorted` instead.

Comment: Oh ok yeah I did that but still not doing much good. I also changed the return to return asd instead of sorted

Comment: @vikingsteve not sure what you mean

Comment: possible duplicate of [int\[\] array (sort lowest to highest)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9791024/int-array-sort-lowest-to-highest)

Comment: Alsho check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9791024/int-array-sort-lowest-to-highest)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were some issues in your code, they are fixed as per below:

```
public class Mode {
    public int [] sort(int[] asd) {
        int[] sorted = asd.clone();
        for (int i = 0; i < sorted.length; i++) {
            for (int j = i+1; j < sorted.length; j++) {
                if ( (sorted[i] > sorted[j]) && (i != j) ) {
                    int temp = sorted[j];
                    sorted[j] = sorted[i];
                    sorted[i] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
        return sorted;
    }

    public int findMode(int[] sorted) {
        // do whatever you want to do here...
        return 0;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Mode list1 = new Mode();
        int[] array = {3,2,5,4,1,1,1,1,10,9};
        int[] potato = list1.sort(array);
        for (int i = 0; i < potato.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(potato[i] + ",");
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.print(list1.findMode(potato));
    }
}
```

To explain, previously you were sorting `asd`. Now we are sorting `sorted`, which starts as a copy of `asd`.

The loop for `j` should start at `i+1`.

The last part of your "swap" operation should be `sorted[i] = temp`.

Comment: thank you! I have one more question. So since this is in a method, can I call upon the sorted list in another method?

Like if I had another method public int[] findMode(sorted)

Comment: Yes, you sure can. The `sorted` array was properly allocated in heap memory (via `clone()`), it will persist in memory and can indeed be used in other methods any way you wish as long as you maintain a reference to it (after which, it will eventually be garbage collected).

Comment: I tried doing it and i got an error saying identifier expected.
this is what I did public int findMode(sorted) or should I just do public int findMode() and put sorted inside the method itself?

Comment: Well when you call the `findMode` method, you should pass in the correct variable. This, at the end of your main method would be `findMode(potato)`. The correct declaration for the method would be `public int findMode(int[] sorted) { ... }`. Please see my amended answer - does this help?

Comment: poh ok i understand. What does private mean? instead of public

Comment: public and private are two of the four `access modifiers` in java that determine whether the methods can be accessed (invoked) by other classes (or not) - google `java access modifiers` and `encapsulation` to find some nice overviews. Have fun with java!

Answer (score 1):

You can use **java.util.Arrays** to sort the array in ascending order

```
public class SortArray {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] array = { 3, 2, 5, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 10, 9 };
        Arrays.sort(array);
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(array[i] + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

The output for the above code snippet will be

```
1 1 1 1 2 3 4 5 9 10
```

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning to elements of `asd` in your sort method, then returning the array `sorted`, which is never altered in your `sort` method.

Additionally, you should initialise your `sorted` array to be the same size as `asd`.

Comment: I got rid of the array sorted and just return asd instead but sitll not working