# Given a list of integers find the highest value obtainable and concatenate in descending order?

Tags: javascript, sorting, arraylist

If the array is `[1,213,214]`

It should return `2142131`. 
How can i do it in javascript?

Comment: Sort the array in descending order, then concatenate the each element.

Comment: check this out and combine it with the previous answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9791024/int-array-sort-lowest-to-highest

Comment: it can be [213,1,214] it should result 2142131 for any array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
array.sort(function(a, b){return a-b});

for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) 
     console.log(array[i]);
```

Use this if you get stuck sorting in the future: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp

Answer (score 2):

Use `sort` on the array with a function to compare in the reverse ordering:

```
t = [1, 213, 214]
t.sort(function(a, b) { return b - a; })
```

Then stringify the array with no separator using `join`:

```
s = t.join("")
```

Comment: This will not work consider this set `[8, 718, 99]`. You will get `718998` instead of `998718`.