# How to sort an array of random numbers

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I need to create an array of size 500, and data is randomly distributed and I'm really confused about how to sort this array. Can somebody help me, please?

The code for random:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class SortTest {

   public static void main(String[] args) { 

      // create an instance of Random class for random number generation 
      Random random = new Random (1L);

      // begin new scope
      {
      // create an int array of 500 elements
      int[] dataArray = new int[500];

      // populate the array with randomly generated values
      for (int index = 0; index < 500; index++)
        dataArray[index] = random.nextInt();

      // end scope
      }

  }
}
```

Do I need use Arrays.sort(dataArray)? Or Arrays.sort(dataArray, Collections.reverseOrder())? But I heard somebody said those are not for primary class.

Please help!!! Thank you!!

Here should be my steps:

1. Create a 500-element integer array using the Random class’s nextInt() method
2. Make a copy of this array and use it as a parameter to sort methods (array is passed by
   reference).
3. Measure execution time to sort the 500-element array using bubble, selection, insertion,
   quicksort, and mergesort
4. Create a 5000000-element integer array using the Random class’s nextInt() method.
5. Make a copy of this array and use it as a parameter to sort methods (array is passed by
   reference).
6. Measure execution time to sort the 5000000-element array using bubble, selection, insertion,
   quicksort, and mergesort.
7. Measure execution time to sort an already sorted (in increasing order) 500-element array
   using bubble, selection, insertion, quicksort, and mergesort.
8. Measure execution time to sort an already reverse sorted (in decreasing order) 500-
   element array using bubble, selection, insertion, quicksort, and mergesort.
9. Measure execution time to sort an already sorted (in increasing order) 5000000-element
   array using bubble, selection, insertion, quicksort, and mergesort.
10. Measure execution time to sort an already reverse sorted (in decreasing order) 5000000-
    element array using bubble, selection, insertion, quicksort, and mergesort.
11. Tabulate your results and comment on sensitivity of the six sorting algorithms on input
    data distribution

I'm confused about strp 7 and 8, how can I sort that array distributed above. And where I should add that in? I used Arrays.sort() but the result was printed out is not in increasing order.

Comment: You can use Arrays.sort(dataArray), it will sort in ascending order

Comment: Possible duplicate of [int\[\] array (sort lowest to highest)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9791024/int-array-sort-lowest-to-highest)

Comment: Did you successfully use the `Arrays.sort(dataArray)` ? because it's pretty straightforward. Can you clarify on what you're asking other than it's about sorting?

Comment: When you say "those are not for primary class" do you mean that you aren't aloud to use external code like the `Arrays` class in your classroom?

Comment: The cited duplicate question answers for how to sort highest to lowest also.

Comment: By *primary class*, do you mean *primitive types*?

Comment: Following from @ElliottFrisch, if the assignment is to *implement* a sorting algorithm, then the `Arrays.sort` or various approaches with `Comparable` are probably not appropriate. If the goal is merely *to sort*, then use one of these Java sorting approaches.

Comment: "*I heard somebody said*" it would be better to follow up with that somebody and understand what they meant, rather than citing them out of context (and presumably incorrectly) on SO. They can probably help you understand.

Comment: I post my assignment steps, and I tried Array.sort, the result was printed is not sorted.

Comment: for (int index = 0; index < 500; index++)
        dataArray[index] = random.nextInt();
      Arrays.sort(dataArray);

Comment: Is that right? I am really lost.

Comment: Never mind, guys! Thank you for your all help!!

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking about a good way to get a sorted array of random numbers, here's a simple solution using Java 8 streams:

```
int[] randoms = Random.ints(500).sorted().toArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

either use this method  `public static void sort(int[]);` from `java.util.Arrays` Class

`Arrays.sort(dataArray);` 
       OR

Change your array declaration from

```
int[] dataArray = new int[500];
```

to

```
ArrayList<Integer> dataArray = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

and then you may apply `sort()` method from `Collection` Class to Sort your Array. beacause `Integer` is a `Comparable` type of Class.

```
public final class java.lang.Integer extends java.lang.Number implements Comparable<java.lang.Integer>
```

Comment: No, `Arrays.sort()` is overloaded for manipulating the primitive data types also. [Here's the implementation for `Arrays.sort(int[])`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(int[]))

Comment: I was adding this Info. I have edited my answer and inbetween you put a `downvote`. @4castle

Comment: At first I was talking about `sort()` method belonging to `Collections` Actually. @4castle

Comment: And after I changed to ArrayList, I don't know how to sort that array